# Should I replace switch case of functions determined by options in previous activity?

Tags: object-oriented, coding-style, android, callbacks, activity

For example, assume my app has 3 steps with 3 pages:

Step 1 : MainActivity: choose color

[image]

---

Step 2 : EditTextActivity: input text

[image]

---

Step 3 : GreenActivity: display color and input text

[image]

---

In EditTextActivity, which activity to go after Next pressed depends on previous MainActivity, so I write a switch case to do that:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setTitle("Step 1");
    }

    public void redTheme(View view){
        Intent i=new Intent(this,EditTextActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("callbackId",0);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }

    public void greenTheme(View view){
        Intent i=new Intent(this,EditTextActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("callbackId",1);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }

    //similar for BlueActivity
    .
    .
    .
}
```

EditTextActivity:

```
public class EditTextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int callbackId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_text);
        this.setTitle("Step 2");
        this.callbackId=this.getIntent().getIntExtra("callbackId",0);
    }

    public void next(View view){
        switch (this.callbackId){
            case 0: {
                Intent i2 = new Intent(this, RedActivity.class);
                EditText editText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                i2.putExtra("text", editText.getText().toString());
                this.startActivity(i2);
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                Intent i2 = new Intent(this, GreenActivity.class);
                EditText editText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                i2.putExtra("text", editText.getText().toString());
                this.startActivity(i2);
                break;
            }
            //similar for BlueActivity
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
}
```

But I think it is an maintain nightmare: when I add a new color Activity, eg: YellowActivity, I need to edit both the MainActivity and EditTextActivity and then add a new switch option. I would like the logic of Next button placed in MainActivity and so I use my own callback mechanism:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setTitle("Step 1");
    }

    public void redTheme(View view){
        Intent i=new Intent(this,EditTextActivity.class);
        final EditTextActivity.Callback callback= new EditTextActivity.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void run(EditTextActivity editTextActivity) {
                Intent i2=new Intent(editTextActivity,RedActivity.class);
                EditText editText=(EditText)editTextActivity.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                i2.putExtra("text",editText.getText().toString());
                editTextActivity.startActivity(i2);
                EditTextActivity.callbackMap.remove(editTextActivity.callbackId);
            }
        };
        int hashCode=callback.hashCode();
        EditTextActivity.callbackMap.put(hashCode,callback);
        i.putExtra("callbackId",hashCode);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }

    public void greenTheme(View view){
        Intent i=new Intent(this,EditTextActivity.class);
        final EditTextActivity.Callback callback= new EditTextActivity.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void run(EditTextActivity editTextActivity) {
                Intent i2=new Intent(editTextActivity,GreenActivity.class);
                EditText editText=(EditText)editTextActivity.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                i2.putExtra("text",editText.getText().toString());
                editTextActivity.startActivity(i2);
                EditTextActivity.callbackMap.remove(editTextActivity.callbackId);
            }
        };
        int hashCode=callback.hashCode();
        EditTextActivity.callbackMap.put(hashCode,callback);
        i.putExtra("callbackId",hashCode);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }

    //similar for BlueActivity
    .
    .
    .
}
```

EditTextActivity:

```
public class EditTextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public interface Callback{
        public void run(EditTextActivity editTextActivity);
    }
    public static Map<Integer,Callback> callbackMap=new HashMap<>();

    public int callbackId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_text);
        this.setTitle("Step 2");
        this.callbackId=this.getIntent().getIntExtra("callbackId",0);
    }

    public void buttonPressed(View view){
        callbackMap.get(this.callbackId).run(this);
    }
}
```

Which I use a static map to hold callbacks instead of embedded in switch case, and now I can add a new operation of Next button without modifying EditTextActivity.

However, I found this mechanism is far more complicated than the original one:

1. It contains more codes
2. The new approach is less straight forward than the original one, which I afraid my teammates would fail to understand what I'm trying to do.
3. The standard way in many docs seems just use switch case

So my question is: should I eliminate switch case at this case?

Note : I'm asking about the general approach of passing functions or callbacks to subsequent activity, not specific for this case. So don't make suggestions like "passing color string to EditTextActivity".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refactoring Switch Statements and is there any real use for Switch Statements at all?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147214/refactoring-switch-statements-and-is-there-any-real-use-for-switch-statements-at)

Comment: What I find worse than using a `switch` here is that you have a lot of unnecessary duplication in your code. Please get rid of it at least for the sake of a simplistic example.

Answer (score 2):

By factoring out the duplicated code first, you can come to a completely different solution.

If I take the first version (with switch) and refactor the duplicated code, you end up with something like

```
public class EditTextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int callbackId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_text);
        this.setTitle("Step 2");
        this.callbackId=this.getIntent().getIntExtra("callbackId",0);
    }

    public void next(View view){
        Intent i2;
        switch (this.callbackId){
            case 0: {
                i2 = new Intent(this, RedActivity.class);
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                i2 = new Intent(this, GreenActivity.class);
                break;
            }
            //similar for BlueActivity
            .
            .
            .
        }
        EditText editText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        i2.putExtra("text", editText.getText().toString());
        this.startActivity(i2);
    }
}
```

Now you can see that the only real variation is which `Intent` to create for the follow-on activity.
A logical change now is to not pass in an int, but rather the `Intent` to activate next, or the Activity class that should be used to create the `Intent`.
As passing objects that way doesn't really seem feasible in Android, the next best thing is similar to the static map you used:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setTitle("Step 1");
    }

    public void redTheme(View view){
        Intent i=new Intent(this,EditTextActivity.class);
        int hashCode=callback.hashCode();
        EditTextActivity.callbackMap.put(hashCode,RedActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("callbackId",hashCode);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }

    public void greenTheme(View view){
        Intent i=new Intent(this,EditTextActivity.class);
        int hashCode=callback.hashCode();
        EditTextActivity.callbackMap.put(hashCode,GreenActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("callbackId",hashCode);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }

    //similar for BlueActivity
    .
    .
    .
}
```

EditTextActivity:

```
public class EditTextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static Map<Integer,Class<? extends Activity>> callbackMap=new HashMap<>();

    public int callbackId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_text);
        this.setTitle("Step 2");
        this.callbackId=this.getIntent().getIntExtra("callbackId",0);
    }

    public void next(View view){
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, callbackMap.get(this.callbackId));
        EditText editText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        i2.putExtra("text", editText.getText().toString());
        this.startActivity(i2);
    }
}
```